# blocked by CORS policy mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

when i call api form ionic to sever mvc5 vs iis7 on winserve2008 meet error :has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".But when calling by postmant, run normally. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the CORS issue means Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

It allows the communication across domains. By enabling it for our server APIs - we allow our services to have communications across the domains. By default browsers will not allow it, unless we pass set http header explicitly.

If you want to solve this issue, I suggest you could add below setting inside the web.config.

```
<system.webServer>

    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

</system.webServer>
```